# React Native Navigation and navigating to another Screen problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a component LatestAdded.js in HomeScreen.js and when its pressed I want to navigate to another Screen named ProductDetailScreen.js but I am facing a problem when the HomeScreen.js is rendering it navigates directly to ProductDetailScreen.js and if I press the back button and navigate to HomeScreen.js and press the LatestAdded.js Component it shows **an error true is not a function (evaluating this.props.viewdetail())**

LastedAdded.js

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
            this.props.viewdetail();
        }}>

            <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                borderRadius: 4,
                borderWidth: 0.5,
                borderColor: '#d6d7da', width: 180, padding: 5, marginRight: 5, height: 120
            }}>
                <View style={{}}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, marginTop: 20 }}> {this.props.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: '700', marginTop: 10, marginBottom:10 }}> {this.props.author}</Text>
                    <StarRating
                        disabled={false}
                        maxStars={5}
                        starSize= {10}
                        rating={3}
                        fullStarColor= '#EDC430'
                        selectedStar={(rating) => this.onStarRatingPress(rating)}
                    />


                </View>
                <Image style={{ width: 80, height: 100, margin: 2 }} source={{ uri: this.props.image }} />

            </View>

        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

render methon in HomeScreen.js

```
 renderItem = ({ item }) => {
return (
  <LatestAdded title={item.pro_name} author={item.pro_price} image={item.img_path}
   viewdetail = { this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail',{pro:item.pro_id})} />
)}
```

ProductDetailScreen.js

```
class ProductDetailScreen extends Component {

render() {
const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = navigation.getParam('pro', 'none');
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{itemId}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: `() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail',{pro:item.pro_id})`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
viewdetail = { this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail',{pro:item.pro_id})}
```

You want to pass a function to be called later but instead you call the function right away

Try this instead:

```
viewdetail = { () => {this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail',{pro:item.pro_id})}}
```